# deleting a row in data frame ; adjusting a string

Tags: dataframe

using the below process to extract SPX constituents from SPY US holdings.

I cannot solve 2 issues.

1. One of the returned rows has a value of CASH_USD. i would like to know how to delete this row.
2. I need to amend the string BRK.B to BRK-B

Any help would be most welcome!

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

url = "https://www.ssga.com/us/en/intermediary/etfs/library-content/products/fund-data/etfs/us/holdings-daily-us-en-spy.xlsx"

# Read data from the excel file, starting from the 5th row
df = pd.read_excel(url, header=4)

# Drop Rows with NaN Values in place
df.dropna(inplace=True)

#Delete unwanted Columns
df.drop(df.columns[[0,2,3,4,5,6,7]], axis=1, inplace = True)

# Print updated Dataframe
print(df)

# Save the updated DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv("SPX_constituents.csv", index=False)

# Print confirmation message
print("Data saved to SPX_constituents.csv")
```

tried multiple things!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.